# Sample code to show how to use Avalondock in an MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I am trying to use AvalonDock in my wpf application which is an MVVM application. Looking around I could not find any sample application showing how can I do this.

AlavonDock says that it has native support for MVVM, so it should be easy to support mvvm, but there is no sample code.

My questions are:

1. How to write xaml that has a document manager and it is binded to
   viewmodel?
2. How to add a new document to panel in this scenario?
3. How can I get information about layout from documentmanegr (if it is possible).

Comment: There is a current GitHub repository for AvalonDock version 3.5 with 4-5 different sample implementations (including theming ligth/dark) and WinForms:
[GitHub project with plenty of samples](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock) ...and using Google Search over all GitHub repos using AvalonDock as keywork should also be useful to find more samples:
[Google search over Github repositories](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&as_q=avalondock&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=github.com&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)

Answer (score 19):

there is an Example App in the CodePlex Source of AvalonDock - it's not included in the normal download. You'll need to go to the [Source Control page](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#) and click on 'Download'.

Additionally, I've written an example App, that you can also use to get started, I wrote a [quick blog post describing it](http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/AvalonDock-2.0-with-MVVM) and [put it on GitHub](https://github.com/8/AvalonDockMVVM).

Basically, you can set the `LayoutItemContainerStyle` to bridge the gap between the View and your ViewModel, for example:

```
<Window ...
  xmlns:dock="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
  xmlns:dockctrl="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Controls;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock"
  >
  ...
  <dock:DockingManager DataContext="{Binding DockManagerViewModel}"
                       DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}" >

    <dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
      <!-- you can add additional bindings from the layoutitem to the DockWindowViewModel -->
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
        <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose}" />
      </Style>
    </dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

  </dock:DockingManager>

</Window>
```

In this example, DockManagerViewModel has a property 'Documents' with a collection of ViewModels that have a Title, CloseCommand and CanClose property.

Comment: This is a really good example ... using AvalonDock 2.0 with the MVVM design paradigm