# How can I create Anchorables and Document Panes and assign documents and anchorables to them using Avalon dock coexisting with MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I managed to understand a basic binding with Avalon looking into following sample:
[Sample code to show how to use Avalondock in an MVVM application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406451/sample-code-to-show-how-to-use-avalondock-in-an-mvvm-application)

But I can't understand how to create a pane and place a child Document or an Anchorable on it.

From what I thought there must be some `Children` property in the `Pane` class that implements `ILayoutContainer`, but I can't access it.

```
<avalon:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager" 
                           Grid.Row="2" 
                           BorderBrush="Black"
                           Margin="3"
                           Background="#FFFDFDFD"
                           BorderThickness="0"
                           AllowMixedOrientation="True" 
                           DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                           AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}">
```

That code allows me to bind Documents and Anchorables, but not panes.
Basically, I want to bind panes to some property in a docking-manager-view-model and bind documents/anchorables to a collection in a pane-view-model.

Comment: So, i get that i can workaround ILayoutUpdateStrategy and get something that remind what i want. I will update post, if i get a solution.